# Gensim: how to load pretrained doc2vec model?

Tags: python, model, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I'm trying to read my pretrained doc2vec model:

```
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
model = Doc2Vec.load('/path/to/pretrained/model')
```

However, an error appears during reading process. Could anyone suggest how to deal with this? Here is the error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-819b254ac835> in <module>()
----> 1 model = Doc2Vec.load('/path/to/pretrained/model')

/opt/jupyter-notebook/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.pyc in load(cls, *args, **kwargs)
   1682     @classmethod    
   1683     def load(cls, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1684         model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
   1685         # update older models
   1686         if hasattr(model, 'table'):

/opt/jupyter-notebook/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.pyc in load(cls, fname, mmap)
    246         compress, subname = SaveLoad._adapt_by_suffix(fname)
    247 
--> 248         obj = unpickle(fname)
    249         obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
    250         return obj

/opt/jupyter-notebook/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.pyc in unpickle(fname)
    909     with smart_open(fname) as f:
    910         # Because of loading from S3 load can't be used (missing readline in smart_open)
--> 911         return _pickle.loads(f.read())
    912 
    913 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'defaultdict'
```

Comment: I guess it may be some problem related with format of "pretrained/model", you may use Doc2Vec to save one and load to test whether it works

Comment: Try to update gensim from GitHub repo. This bug was fixed 6 days ago. https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/853

Comment: Seems to be exactly what I need: the model appeared to be saved via Python 3, and I'm trying to load it with Python 2. However, after I updated gensim from its GitHub repo, nothing has changed...

Comment: Maybe I've chosen the wrong branch? Isn't this bug fixed in **'develop'** branch?

Comment: This fix has appeared in release 0.13.4 and merged with master branch 3 days ago. You can find your problem in list of changes here https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/commit/e8383913b6d21ec0aaba3f422e05fe820c0bcc6d. You can try to remove your gensim and install it from repo again by instruction from "Installation".

Comment: where can i find the stored trained model?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments to the question, this was likely related to an issue in gensim that was fixed in 0.13.4 release.